# Do I need Remote Desktop to automatically remotely install applications on remote OS X clients?

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop, osx-snow-leopard

I have OS X server set up as a directory server with portable home directories.  I'd like to guarantee the 3-4 client Macs all have the same applications and versions installed without having to manually install everything.  All I can find is documentation on how to set up the update server.

Do I need to get Remote Desktop 3 to be able to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of tools that'll let you manage client software centrally: [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), [radmind](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/radmind/), [filewave](http://www.filewave.com/), [Puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Puppet_Mac_Osx), [JAMF's Casper suite](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/), ... as well as the option of scripting it yourself.  However, all of these will involve a fair bit of up-front effort and/or expense; for only 3-4 clients, it's generally easiest to just manage the computers manually.

Comment: There's also StarDeploy (http://stardeploy.com/) and munki (http://code.google.com/p/munki/) for managing a software repo that the client macs connect to and download/install software from.